# Load xlsx package using R.NET

Tags: c#, r, r.net

I'm trying to load the xlsx package to read the excel file `engine.Evaluate("load(xlsx)");`
However, an stackoverflow exception is thrown. So, do we have any ways to load a R package or how can we read an excel file using r.net ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `library` to load and attach a package in R, not `load`.

Comment: thank @Konrad for the answer, the same exception is thrown with `library(xlsx)`

Answer (score 0):

There have been some recent updates to R.NET in the past month, including fixes for compatibility with R 3.5+.  If you are not running the latest version (currently 1.8.2), I would recommend updating from NuGet or getting the latest code: https://github.com/rdotnet/rdotnet